# How to implement the function to share in a react native application?

Tags: react-native

There is an application (the main essence of the application is working with images) let's call it dodo
Is it possible to implement the functionality that the user does not launch the dodo, selects a photo in his gallery, and there is a function to share, and that in this list of applications in which you can share, there was my dodo. And by clicking on share in the dodo, we go to the dodo on a specific screen.
How can this be realized?